# Inno Setup change CreateOutputMsgMemoPage font

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to change the font that the actual message part of the window created using `CreateOutputMsgMemoPage` displays in?

I need to return some results from a database query to a window in Inno Setup, which I am doing by reading in from a file using:

```
LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\Output.txt'), astrResults);
```

and then creating the page like so:

```
ResultsPage := CreateOutputMsgMemoPage(wpInstalling,
'Results', 'The following results were returned from the database.',
'',
astrResults);
```

The trouble is that I am losing the columnar tab delimited formatting from the text file as the text is being displayed in a variable width font. Therefore, I need to used a fixed width font (e.g. Lucida Console) to maintain the correct formatting. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, `ResultsPage.RichEditViewer.Font.Name := 'Lucida Console';`. You can always find the class description of the returned object in [`Support Classes Reference`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses), `TOutputMsgMemoWizardPage` class in this case, which has two published members from which the `RichEditViewer` one is obviously the content control. Then you just click through the classes to see their members until you find something font related.

Comment: Thanks, @TLama this works great and has allowed me to set the font size as well using `ResultsPage.RichEditViewer.Font.Size := 9`. If you add this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use:

```
ResultsPage.RichEditViewer.Font.Name := 'Lucida Console';
```

to change the font and:

```
ResultsPage.RichEditViewer.Font.Size := 9;
```

to change the size. Thank you @TLama.